# Selecionar option ao clicar em botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou com 3 botões fora da tag form e ao clicar em algum deles, preciso que o valor seja selecionado no select, segue imagem e código para melhor entendimento:

Botões (fora da tag form)

```html
<div class="botoes_action">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <a href="">
      <button class="botao_preto waves-effect waves-light">
        Compre 3 unidades 
        <b>
          receba 1 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <a href="">
      <button class="botao_vermelho waves-effect waves-light">
        Compre 5 unidades 
        <b>
          receba 2 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <a href="">
      <button class="botao_verde waves-effect waves-light">
        Compre 10 unidades 
        <b>
          receba 5 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>



 <form class="formulario_area" action="#" id="form_envio" method="post">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col m12 s12 paddingNone">
       <input type="text" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo">
     </div>
     <div class="input-field col m12 s12 paddingNone">
       <input type="text" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
     </div>
     <div class="input-field col m12 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
       <input type="text" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
     </div>
     <div class=" col m6 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
       <select name="estado" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="estado" onchange="mudaCidade($(this).val());">
       </select>
     </div>
     <div class="col m6 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
       <select name="cidade" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="cidade">
         <option value="cidade">Cidade</option>                           
       </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col m12 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
       <select name="pacote" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="pacote">
         <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Escolha uma unidade</option>  
         <option value="3">3 Unidades</option>       
         <option value="5">5 Unidades</option>   
         <option value="10">10 Unidades</option>                       
       </select>
     </div>                                    
   </div>                               
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 send_btn">
     <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn button_send" data-loading-text="Aguarde..." type="submit">
       Enviar
     </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Ao clicar em um dos três botões, necessito que o último campo do form (unidade) seja pré selecionado.
Porém não tenho a menor ideia de como possa fazer isto;
Alguém já precisou fazer algo semelhante e pode passar alguma dica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
$('.botoes_action button').click(function() {

  $('#pacote').val($(this).data('quantidade'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="botoes_action">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <button class="botao_preto waves-effect waves-light" data-quantidade="3">
        Compre 3 unidades 
        <b>
          receba 1 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <button class="botao_vermelho waves-effect waves-light" data-quantidade="5">
        Compre 5 unidades 
        <b>
          receba 2 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <button class="botao_verde waves-effect waves-light" data-quantidade="10">
        Compre 10 unidades 
        <b>
          receba 5 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col m12 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
    <select name="pacote" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="pacote">
      <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Escolha uma unidade</option>  
      <option value="3">3 Unidades</option>       
      <option value="5">5 Unidades</option>   
      <option value="10">10 Unidades</option>                       
    </select>
  </div>                                    
</div>
```

A primeira coisa a se fazer é tirar a tag `<a href="">` de cima dos botões de ação.

Depois você coloca o atributo `data-quantidade="3"` em cada botão, sendo 3 a quantidade correspondente no `select`.

No javascript eu declarei um evento para monitorar os botões dentro da `div.botoes_action`, e quando um botão é pressionado o script pega o valor da propriedade data-quantidade e atribui ao valor do select.

Answer (score 1):

Ao clicar em um botão, você pode identificar qual é o botão e dessa forma alterar o estado de selecionado ao respectivo elemento `option`:

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#opt" + id).prop("selected","selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="botoes_action">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <a href="">
      <button type="button" id="3" class="botao_preto waves-effect waves-light">
        Compre 3 unidades
        <b>
          receba 1 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <a href="">
      <button type="button" id="5" class="botao_vermelho waves-effect waves-light">
        Compre 5 unidades
        <b>
          receba 2 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <a href="">
      <button type="button" id="10" class="botao_verde waves-effect waves-light">
        Compre 10 unidades
        <b>
          receba 5 de brinde
        </b>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>



<form class="formulario_area" action="#" id="form_envio" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col m12 s12 paddingNone">
      <input type="text" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col m12 s12 paddingNone">
      <input type="text" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col m12 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
      <input type="text" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
    </div>
    <div class=" col m6 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
      <select name="estado" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="estado" onchange="mudaCidade($(this).val());">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col m6 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
      <select name="cidade" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="cidade">
        <option value="cidade">Cidade</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col m12 s12 paddingNone paddingL">
      <select name="pacote" class="form-control box_form" required="" id="pacote">
        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Escolha uma unidade</option>
        <option id="opt3" value="3">3 Unidades</option>
        <option id="opt5" value="5">5 Unidades</option>
        <option id="opt10" value="10">10 Unidades</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 send_btn">
    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn button_send" data-loading-text="Aguarde..." type="submit">
      Enviar
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Dessa forma o usuário não consegue selecionar outro valor após ter clicado nos 3 botões.